# Ruby Scalable String Match

Tags: ruby, string-matching, dfa

I want to match a dictionary of strings to a dictionary of patterns very quickly.

I have 10000 inputs of length 255, and 10000 patterns of length 20. I need to match these strings very quickly and I need to know which patterns matched which inputs.

My patterns need to support regular expression matching. Right now, I have everything in a mysql database and I'm using a regex call in mysql to do what I need. Ex:

```
patterns.each do |p|
  select * from inputs where inputs.value regex #{p}
end
```

but this will get slower and slower the more patterns I have. I also considered:

```
patterns.each do |p|
  inputs.grep(p)
end
```

but it has the same issue when I have too many patterns. I want to create a DFA in ruby and store it in memory (separate worker process) until it's needed, but I don't if there's any resources available for doing something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the matches, just union the regexps; then the speed is in C. Proof of concept:

```
# prepwork:
# make 676 two-letter patterns plus a digit
patterns = ('a'..'z').flat_map { |x| ('a'..'z').map { |y| x + y + "\\d" } }
# convert to regexp
regexp = Regexp.union(patterns.map{ |pattern| /(#{pattern})/ })

# matching:
# match
match = regexp.match("mu5")
# find out which pattern was hit
if match
  puts patterns[match.captures.find_index { |x| x }]
  # => mu\d
end
```

If you need to see which pattern was hit, you either can't use any capturing brackets, or you need to rewrite my example to use named captures instead of plain ones, which shouldn't be too hard.

EDIT: If you *don't* need to see which pattern was hit, you can probably speed it up by removing the parentheses from the regexp, replacing `/(#{pattern})/` with `/#{pattern}/`, so that matching does not need to create a huge array each time.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will benchmark this. Do you by any chance know how the regexp.match method runs? Will it create it's own NFA and DFA or is it implemented in some other way. Are there any specific regex's that might cause the match method to run slowly?

Comment: Newer versions of Ruby run Oniguruma engine, which [this article](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/4/3/exploring-rubys-regular-expression-algorithm) explores in some detail. If you haven't found your answer, you can duplicate their work (enable debugging flags, compile Ruby from source) to see for yourself exactly what your regexp is doing. And yes, there are specific patterns that match extremely slowly, called ["catastrophic backtracking cases"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), but Oniguruma squashes most of those cases rather efficiently (unlike some other engines).

Comment: But in fact, the linked article shows some of those catastrophic cases so you can see for yourself how they work (or don't).